# shell script : find the last integer number from a file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a file called `sample.txt` and the values inside the files are like this:

<sup>Editor's note: the sample lines originally had empty lines between them, but the OP has since confirmed that was accidental.</sup>

```
100
200
300
hiiiii
```

last value is may be null a string or anything other than number....

How can i get the last integer value from the file using unix scripting. the output i am expecting is 300..

i tried the below command but i am getting only *hiiiii* from this

```
value=`cat $working_tmp_dir/sample.txt|tail -3| head -1|cut -f2 -d'='|cut -b 1-8`
```

Comment: What result do you want when sample.txt has no digits at all ?

Answer (score 2):

```
grep  -Eo '^[0-9]+$' hi.txt | tail -1
```

where hi.txt is your file

Answer (score 2):

`awk` would work well here too:

```
awk  '{ if ($1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/) lastnumber=$1 } END {print lastnumber}' <yourfile.txt>
```

`awk` will go through each line in your file and run it through the script inside the single quotes here.

The script, in layman's terms says "Test the first field ($1) of the line to see if it matches this regex, which is looking for a string that is only numeric. If it find a match, then store that match in the variable `lastnumber`. As awk moves down the file, it changes `lastnumber` as it finds fully numeric strings in the first field. When it is done (`END`) processing the file, it prints the value stored in the `lastnumber` variable.

That being said, if your system supports `tac`, I would recommend @karakfa's answer as that is going to be more efficient for larger files.

I would also highly recommend to read @mklement0's excellent answer as it uses this same logic, but applies to the entire line of the file and is a much more concise script. Their explanation is very well put together also.

Comment: I think the real miss on this answer is that it lacks an explanation about what `awk` is doing here. I'm going to fix that now. I wrote it with the implicit `if` and the reference to a specific field because that's how one, more often then not, uses `awk` and it's a good learning experience for someone that is unfamiliar with `awk` which would be the same population of people that are coming to this site for answers to OP's question. Refactoring your script to the point that only someone already familiar with `awk` seems to defeat the purpose of SO. But... to each their own.

Comment: Thanks for adding an explanation and for the plug. I usually opt for an _idiomatic_ and, if possible, _efficient_ solution, even if that may be harder to understand at first - that's where a good explanation comes in. Those that are merely interested in a ready-made solution won't care about the didactic aspects of an answer, and those interested in understanding the solution will be aided by the explanation.

Comment: As for performance with large files: @karakfa's answer will be (potentially much) faster the closer the last number in the file is to the  _end_ of the file (compared to my similarly short-circuiting solution). With smaller files, even your solution, which always parses _all_ lines, may outperform the `tac` solution, especially with a fast Awk such as `mawk`.

Answer (score 2):

another alternative

```
$ tac file | awk '/^[0-9]+$/{print;exit}'

300
```

reverse the file, print the first number.

Comment: That's lovely! I didn't know about `tac`. Someone had a sense of humor naming that one.

Comment: @JNevill: Note that `tac` is not a POSIX utility and that not all platforms have it; on BSD/OSX, use `tail -r`.

Comment: It's on my ancient Suse box at work, so it must be pretty common.

Comment: @JNevill: Yes, on _Linux_.

Comment: There's other operating systems? ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **GNU** `grep` command with `-P` (PCRE) with `-z` option that reads whole file at once:

```
grep -oPz '\d+(?=\D*\z)' file

300
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your integers:

- start on the first line
- are all in a single block of contiguous lines

you can use this efficient single-command solution (POSIX-compliant):

```
awk '/^[0-9]+$/ { n=$0; next } { print n; exit }' sample.txt
```

<sup>Note: Even though [karakfa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35638590/45375) involves an additional utility, `tac`, his answer will likely be faster with large files whose last number is close to the end of the file.</sup>

- `/^[0-9]+$/` matches a line consisting of decimal digits only, i.e., a decimal number (possibly with leading zeros).
- `{ n=$0; next }` saves that line (`$0`) in variable `n` and starts processing of the next line (`next`; skips the remaining commands in the script).
- `{ print n; exit }` is therefore first executed for the first line that does *not* consist of decimal digits only; `n`, which at that point contains the *last* decimal number encountered, is printed, and `exit` terminates processing altogether.

Comment: blank lines are just formatting problem.. there is no black like between lines. i will try this .. thanks

Comment: file at the end of the line is my file name right ?

Comment: guys i am still having problem i think.... i will explain what is happening here.. i am getting some values from a table and storing into a file and when i do that i am getting null value at the end. that means i am just getting a space i think......so still when i use the above solutions i am getting null as partition... so i want the script to avoid that null and take the number above that..

Comment: @sarath: At this point I suggest you accept the existing answer that best answers your question _as originally stated_, and create a _new_ question that explains _in detail_ the problem you're still having. Expanding a question later is a bad idea, once several answers asking the original form of the question have been posted. Feel free to post a link to the new question in a comment here.

Comment: ok thanks.. what happened was i didnt even know that i am getting a space at the end.. i noticed that after when i tried all you guys answers.. okie i will create another question and i will ask... thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This will match the numbers in the file and print the last one.

`grep -o "[0-9]*" sample.txt | tail -n 1`

Comment: this only catches the last digit

Comment: guys i am still having problem i think.... i will explain what is happening here.. i am getting some values from a table and storing into a file and when i do that i am getting null value at the end. that means i am just getting a space i think......so still when i use the above solutions i am getting null as partition... so i want the script to avoid that null and take the number above that..

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative

`grep -x '[0-9 ]*' hi.txt | tail -1`

(I decided to also allow spaces)

Comment: does not work for me (grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD)